# how do you sign a message with your monero private key?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, messagesigning

How do you sign a message with your monero private key using the cli-wallet, gui-wallet, and last with pure js using what libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *monero-wallet-cli*, you can sign the content of a file (e.g. message_file)  with the command `sign message_file`, and verify the signature with `verify message_file address_of_the_signer signature`.

With *monero-wallet-gui*, in the menu go to `Advanced -> Sign/Verify`, then you can sign (or verify) a message or a file by filling the appropriate boxes.